# how can i see asp code(text in color) in Visual studio2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp-classic

I have an asp page and want to see it in VS2008 with color like html code. what setting should i change to allow asp page to be viewed correctely?

Answer (score 0):

In my, as far as I can see, stock configuration, ASP files are highlighted as I would expect, with VBScript blocks and HTML tags highlighted consistently with .Net code. You can force things to change, including which editor personality to open the ASP files with, in Tools | Options | Text Editor.

Comment: in my text editor option i do not see asp as a Language
All boxes has checked but stilll not working.

Comment: What developer profile do you have set? Try setting the Web Developer preferences to see if that gets your highlighting as you wish it. Also, check what is installed in terms of extensions.